# How/Why does ref return for instance members

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, return, jit, ref

I'm trying to understand why/how does ref-return for the case of returning refs to members of a class.
In other words, I want to understand the internal workings of the runtime that guarantee why ref-return of a instance member works, from the memory safety aspect of the CLR.

The specific feature I'm referring to is mentioned in the  [ref-return documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) which specifically states:

> The return value cannot be a local variable in the method that returns it; it must have a scope that is outside the method that returns it. It can be an instance or static field of a class, or it can be an argument passed to the method. Attempting to return a local variable generates compiler error CS8168, "Cannot return local 'obj' by reference because it is not a ref local."

Here's a code snippet that cleanly compiles and runs and demonstrates returning an instance field as ref return:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace refreturn
{
    public struct SomeStruct {
        public int X1;
    }

    public class SomeClass {
        SomeStruct _s;
        public ref SomeStruct S => ref _s;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = new SomeClass();                     
            // This will store a direct pointer to x.S
            ref var s = ref x.S;               
            // And now the GC will be free to re-use this memory
            x = null;          
            // Why should s.X1 be considered safe?
            Console.WriteLine(s.X1 + 0x666);
        }
    }
}
```

My question for this code is: What is the underlying mechanism in the GC that ensures that it keeps tracking the `SomeClass` instance after that last refernce to it had supposedly been set to null?
More precisely...:

Given that the local `s` stores a direct pointer to the `_s` member of the SomeClass instance  (disassembly from windbg below) whose last "explicit" reference is overwritten with null in the following line (`x = null`), How does the GC keep track of the live-root to the `SomeClass` instance which would prevent this program from crashing...?

Windbg Disassembly:

```
007ff9`e01504dc e8affbffff      call    00007ff9`e0150090 (refreturn.SomeClass.get_S(), mdToken: 0000000006000001)
                                  //rbp-30h stores the pointer to the struct
00007ff9`e01504e1 488945d0        mov     qword ptr [rbp-30h],rax
                                  // Now it's copied to rcx
00007ff9`e01504e5 488b4dd0        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rbp-30h]
                                  // And now copied to rbp-20h
00007ff9`e01504e9 48894de0        mov     qword ptr [rbp-20h],rcx
00007ff9`e01504ed 33c9            xor     ecx,ecx
                                  // The last reference is overwritten with null
00007ff9`e01504ef 48894de8        mov     qword ptr [rbp-18h],rcx
                                  // rbp-20h is copied to rcx again
00007ff9`e01504f3 488b4de0        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rbp-20h]
                                  // Isn't this a possible boom?!?!?
00007ff9`e01504f7 8b09            mov     ecx,dword ptr [rcx]
00007ff9`e01504f9 81c19a020000    add     ecx,29Ah
00007ff9`e01504ff e85c634c5d      call    mscorlib_ni+0xd56860 (00007ffa`3d616860) (System.Console.WriteLine(Int32), mdToken: 0000000006000b5b)
00007ff9`e0150504 90              nop
```

Comment: Some of your assumptions are simply wrong.  You're reasoning from incorrect assumptions so your conclusions don't follow. In particular the comment that says that the GC is free to release memory when there is a live root that refers to that memory denies the basic premise of the GC: that it does not free stuff that has live roots!

Comment: I note that if the documentation says what you quoted then the documentation is wrong. It has conflated scope, which is a compile-time concept about the regions of text in which a name is valid, with lifetime.

Comment: Oh, wait, it's **that** documentation.  That documentation is full of incorrect jargon usages. See my big comment at the bottom for a few of them.  I'll add another about "scope".

Comment: Hi Eric, I read your comment, and I was secretly hoping you'd jump on and rip into my assumptions, I never doubted that everything is OK, I just don't understand how/why. In other words, I'm wondering HOW the GC knows of the live root in this specific case...

Comment: Say more clearly then what you don't understand, because as it stands the question sounds like you're asking "why is the GC correct?"

Comment: For example, did you think that the GC only deals with pointers to the object header of a heap object?  That's not right. The GC fully understands that managed pointers can be to the interior of a managed object, and those pointers keep the object alive.

Comment: I note also that we can illustrate your scenario without ref locals. `class C { static C c = new C(); int x; static void M(ref int y) { c = null; y = 123; } static void Main() { M(ref c.x); }}`  The lone instance of C is not eligible for collection immediately after `c = null` because `y` is keeping it alive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 // This will store a direct pointer to x.S
 ref var s = ref x.S;
```

It stores a managed interior pointer to a heap variable; the pointer is stored to a location on the short term store.  The short term store is a root of the GC.

```
// And now the GC will be free to re-use this memory
x = null;
```

Good heavens no.  **There's a living managed interior pointer in a GC root**.

> How does the .NET GC / runtime make sure that this would never result in an access violation or reading wild pointers after the SomeClass backing memory has been re-used for something else?

By not releasing that memory until after the internal managed pointer is no longer a root of the GC.  Or, to put it another way: by implementing a correct garbage collector.

I can't figure out what question you're really asking here. The GC prevents the error *because that is its only job* and it was implemented correctly.

Comment: I guess I'm in my stupid day of the week, but I was under the assumption that the GC would check for pointer(s) to the object's header/begunning , and I guess I'm starting to understand that the GC also keeps track of INTERIOR pointers now...

Comment: @damageboy: Don't be hard on yourself; ignorance is not the same thing as stupidity, and there was a fact you were ignorant of. Being able to efficiently track interior pointers was an important design consideration for the .NET GC, and has serious performance and design implications.

Comment: I understand that now, but I was certain that it only tracks pointers to object headers, I was so positive of it, it never occured to me as a possibility, thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: BTW: It just makes me appreciate the .NET GC that much more now, as the performance implications of this seemingly small detail must be huge...

Comment: @damageboy: No worries. In C++/CLI you can *explicitly* track interior pointers (and pinning pointers), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0fh545k.aspx for details.

Comment: One more question if I may, in the C++/CLI documentation you linked to it's explicitly mentioned that interior pointers may only reside on the stack. Does this limitation also apply generally speaking for the GC?

Comment: @damageboy: **Yes**.  You'll note that in C# 7 you can pass a `ref` in a call, you can put a `ref` in a local, and you can return a `ref` from a call, and *that's all*.  You can't put a `ref` into a field or array element. You can't use `ref` in environments where locals and temporaries are reified as fields of a closure class, like iterator blocks or async methods. You can't use `this` of a struct -- which is secretly `ref` -- in those contexts either (or, in some cases the value is copied.)

Comment: @damageboy: These restrictions exist to ensure that interior pointers and pointers to stack locations never end up stored anywhere other than the stack.  That gives us confidence that there won't be a pointer to a stack frame that has been popped, for example.  The long-term pool only contains pointers to the long-term pool, never the short-term pool or to the interior of long-term pool objects.

Comment: Thanks again! This makes total sense now

Answer (score 1):

> How does the .NET GC / runtime make sure that this would never result in an access violation or reading wild pointers after the SomeClass backing memory has been re-used for something else?

For the exact same reason that `x` won't reference an object that has already been cleaned up by the GC.  You know this because *the GC isn't allowed to clean up an object if it's accessible through managed code*.  The object is reachable both through `x` until you clear it, and also `s`.  `s` is a reference to that object, and needs to be treated as such by the GC when determining if that object is allowed to be collected.